# What does the database error "Field X doesn't have a default value" mean?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Below is my form and table that I have created for my signup newsletter. When I try to enter a new person into the form I get this message. What do I have to do to fix this problem?

> **Field 'ip_address' doesn't have a default value
>   INSERT INTO `member` SET join_date = NOW() , `first_name` = 'John', `last_name` = 'D',
>   `email` = 'jd@aol.com'
>
> Field 'unsubscribe_date' doesn't have a default value
>   INSERT INTO
>   `member` SET join_date = NOW() , `first_name` = 'John', `last_name` =
>   'D', `email` = 'jd@aol.com'
>
> Field 'unsubscribe_send_id' doesn't have a default value
>   INSERT INTO
>   `member` SET join_date = NOW() , `first_name` = 'John', `last_name` =
>   'D', `email` = 'jd@aol.com'**

Here's my form:

```
    <table cellpadding="3" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Email <span class="required">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text_input" name="email" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name <span class="required">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text_input" name="first_name" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text_input" name="last_name" value=""></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>
            Subscribed Communication
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                                                <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="group_id[]" value="2" checked></td>
                            <td>RaceO'Clock Members</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe!"> <br/>
                <em>* required fields</em>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


    </form>
```

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `join_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `unsubscribe_date` date NOT NULL,
  `unsubscribe_send_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`member_id`)
)  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: the fields do no have default values, you are not setting them, they are set to be `NOT NULL` when you created your table.

Comment: You can modify your table to allow `NULL` values in those columns if you wish, though bear in mind they may be expected elsewhere in your application.

Comment: confirm if u have created that column name in your phpmyadmin db table.

Comment: if else copy and create the column name

Answer (score 2):

Fields that are not null without a default value are required in an insert statement.

You have three choices :

1. Define a default value
2. Change the column definition to allow null
3. Add that column to the insert statement

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES that is defined in the %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini file. After removing that setting, restart MySQL to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating table with `NOT NULL` in all columns which means column cant be `NULL` when you insert values.

If you want make `NOT NULL` then you should make a `DEFAULT` value of this column.

Use this:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
     `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `first_name` varchar(255) ,
     `last_name` varchar(255) ,
     `email` varchar(255) ,
      `join_date` date ,
      `ip_address` varchar(15),
      `unsubscribe_date` date ,
      `unsubscribe_send_id` int(11) ,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`member_id`)
    )  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Or** add that column to insert statement and insert a empty string.

Like that:

```
INSERT INTO member SET join_date = NOW() , 
                      first_name = 'John', 
                       last_name = 'D',
                           email = 'jd@aol.com' ,
                      ip_address = '' ,
                unsubscribe_date = '',
             unsubscribe_send_id = ''
```